# how to run local command via ansible-playbook

Tags: ansible

I am trying to run some local command, iterating over inventory file and taking each hostname as an argument to the local command.

Eg: I wanted to run a command "knife node create {{ hostname }}" in my local machine(laptop). The playbook is:

```
- name: Prep node
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: node create
    command: "knife node create {{ hostname | quote }}"
```

and my inventory file looks like:

```
[qa-hosts]
10.10.10.11 hostname=example-server-1
```

Ofcourse, it wont work as the inventory has 'qa-hosts' and the play is for '127.0.0.1', as I wanted the play to run from my local machine.

Would anyone help me with an idea how to get it done. Basically, I want get the variable 'hostname' and pass it to above play block.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could access the hostname by using the following play, as the inventory information are available as hostvars.

```
- hosts: 127.0.0.1   
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - debug: var=hostvars

    - name: node create
      command: "knife node create {{ hostvars[item]['hostname'] }}"
      with_items:
        - "{{ groups['qa-hosts'] }}"
```

Answer (score 12):

I like **delegate_to**.  Here's an example that, on **localhost**, runs **getent hosts** for each host:

```
---
- hosts: all
  connection: ssh
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:
  - name: Lookup ansible_hostname in getent database
    command: getent hosts {{ ansible_hostname }}
    delegate_to: localhost
    register: result

  - name: Show results
    debug:
      var: result.stdout
    delegate_to: localhost
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! I was looking around how to use my API from the ansible machine not from a target host, this was only a part of the whole role. 
This works with ansible `uri` section as well.

Answer (score 7):

Another alternative is [local_action](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html?highlight=local_action).

In the case of both `delegate_to` and `local_action`, be aware that if `become = yes` then Ansible will of course implicitly try to invoke the action using `sudo`, and then will probably fail because the password for local `sudo` will be different to any password you entered for remote `sudo`.

Comment: Well, yes, but just add `host_vars/localhost.yml` into your inventory or playbook directory, and put `ansible_become_password` in there.  You can put that in `ansible-vault` if you like.

Answer (score 2):

we can access playbook on localhost machine like:

**file: playbook.yml**

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: Print message
      debug:
        msg: Hello Ansible World
```

**file: hosts**

```
[localhost]
127.0.0.1
```

**Command**

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts  playbook.yml
```